# Grails Twitter Bootstrap with Google Maps

Tags: css, grails, twitter, twitter-bootstrap

Im using Grails in the version 2.0.4 and have the following in my BuildConfig:

```
compile ":twitter-bootstrap:2.0.2.25"
runtime ":fields:1.1"
```

So in fact, Im using the Twitter Bootstrap Plugin. Now, I wanna use a Google Map in my application, but the map does not show up at all, when using the Bootstrap Plugin. When using the map without Bootstrap, it works totally. The file, in which Im using the Map looks like follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main">
    <title>YouPlace</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=de"></script>
    <g:javascript src="googleWrapper.js" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mapCanvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, nothing special, I thought. But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Edit: I created a container called map, which has following css:

```
.map {
    padding: 100px;
}
```

Now I can see the map, but the map is not going over the whole page. How can I say, that it should go over the whole page. I tried padding: 100%, but then it goes over the page, but much more and I can't see the end of the map.

Comment: do you get any javascript errors in firebug?

Comment: No, there aren't any errors. Its really just a Twitter Bootstrap issue. Im not the css pro, to check which part I should change to make it work. :p

Comment: Need to put up and example, for instance maybe on jsFiddle

Comment: Did you fixed? maybe setting the height to 100% to your component (#mapCanvas) can you provide a screenshot? Regards